# Redirect All Subdomains to Root

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, root

I need all subdomains to redirect back to the root.

Ex). test.website.ca -> https://www.website.ca
fake1.website.ca -> https://www.website.ca
www.ggg.website.ca/ -> https://www.website.ca
etc.

Here is the code that I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.website\.ca$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.website.ca/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.website\.ca$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.website.ca%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Without the uri, use same RewriteCond and:

```
RewriteRule ^ https://www.website.ca/ [L,R=301]
```